# [{a: 1}],[{b: 2}] Converted to {a:1,b:2}

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = [
{a: 1},
{b: 2},
{c: 3}
]
```

Is there any quick way for this to become

{a:1, b:2, c:3}

In actual scenarios, not only 3 Object, but also hundreds of Object

Comment: Only 3 variable you have or it may have more variables?

Comment: can you use an array of objects instead of individual variables for each array?

Comment: @NickParsons ok

Comment: @Ajith Corrected

Comment: Super quick way with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge): `_.merge(true, ...a)`

Comment: @tadman spread operator don't support in old browsers, You need to consider that also

Comment: @Ajith I did mention super quick, not super compatible. I like Pranav's answer better, too, but your point stands. According to Mozilla the only concern is [Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as always.

Comment: @tadman just think my comment as a note for others who try to use spread operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
let res = Object.assign({}, ...a)
```

Comment: Spread operator does'nt work in IE I think and old safari also